# How to create page breaks automatically in CSS?

Tags: html, css, printing

I create a web page with table rows. It is looking good when i press print button. But sometimes page breaks are cutting page middle of the block. I tried to use tbody as this

```
<table>
...
<tbody>
<tr><td>sample datea 1</td></tr>
<tr><td>sample datea 2</td></tr>
<tr><td>sample datea 3</td></tr>
</tbody>
<tbody>...</tbody>
...
</table>
```

When i want to print page it writes as

```
//first page  
sample datea 1 
sample datea 2 
// second page
sample datea 3
```

I want to cut after sample datea 3 . I tried to add blokla's div tag CSS as

```
.blokla{display:block;page-break-inside:avoid; page-break-after:auto}
```

How can i break page between div tags or another ? My main problem is below.

[image]

Comment: can you create a demo?

Comment: see [Using CSS and/or jQuery for Printed Pages with Page Breaks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878013/using-css-and-or-jquery-for-printed-pages-with-page-breaks) for your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this question with this code

```
tbody{page-break-inside:avoid; page-break-after:auto; position:relative;
display:block;}
```

It is working fine.

Comment: You can get rid of the `page-break-after:auto;` and  `position:relative;`. Also, this solution will only work if: a) all of the data in each column is exactly the same width, or b) you set widths on the `td` elements in each `tbody`, and don't add any content that exceeds those widths.

Answer (score 1):

The CSS you have is valid and works on my end.

However the problem you have is that you are creating two `<tbody>` tags in a single table. *This practice is not "valid" HTML* (it is valid). Use only one `<tbody>` and use this CSS;

```
tr{page-break-inside:avoid; page-break-after:auto}
```

Changing the CSS in this way ensures for maximum flexibility in your HTML, presentation for each row will now remain together.

Comment: I don't think that's valid either. Why are you reluctant to use the `page-break-inside` rule on the `<tr>`?

Comment: You can use multiple `tbody` tags inside `table` http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/table.html

Comment: I can add tr but it is not good to me . I need group every 5 tr in a tbody group

Comment: I would, in that case, use separate tables and put the rule on the `<table>` element.