# How to create page breaks automatically?

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to automatically detect when content encroaches upon a page margin and then force a page break with CSS?

[image]

and my code is

```
body {
  font: inherit !important; 
  color: black;
}
.ql-editor *{
  font-family: cwTeXKai !important;
}

table {
  width: 90%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: none;
  margin-top: 18pt;
  border: solid 1pt;
}


td {
  border: solid 1pt;
}

p {
  font-family: cwTeXKai !important;
  display: block;
  margin-block-start: .03em;
  margin-block-end: .03em;
  margin-inline-start: 0px;
  margin-inline-end: 0px;
}
span{
  font-family: cwTeXKai !important;
}

@page {
  size: A4 portrait;
}
```

I have watching this methods, but it's still not working.

```
tbody{
page-break-inside:avoid; 
page-break-after:auto; 
position:relative;
display:block;}
```

so how can auto draw the break border?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create page breaks automatically in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29895654/how-to-create-page-breaks-automatically-in-css)

Comment: can't, it's not working